# Forcing a field uniqueness on the database is it a bad design

Tags: database, database-design

I have the following tables.

1. **Available_Ip_Address** (IP_Address_ID (Primary Key ), description, status ).
2. **Virtual_Machine** (VM_ID (Primary Key ), description, IP_Address (foreign key ) )

The scenario is as follow:-

1. we maintain all the available IP address of a single table.
2. we maintain the virtual machine info in another table , but specific IP address can be assigned to a single VM at any time.
3. so i have added a drop down list when adding a VM which contain all the IP address that have their status as “available”.
4. but since two users can create a VM and they might select the same available IP address
5. so i found that the best way to protect our system is to make the foreign key IP_Address in the Virtual_Machine table unique.
6. then if two users select the same IP address an exception will be raised in the Database for one of them and i can propagate the exception and then display a user friendly message to the user that the IP address might have being already taken.

So is my approach considered a valid design, or i should look for adding a timestamp field on the IP_address field so if the status of the IP address was changed since it was last queried then the record will have new timestamp and a exception will be raised on the application level.

Best Regards

Comment: Current design seems good, but I don't understand the timestamp based enhancement

Comment: so if a user select an IP and save the record, then the IP staus will be chnaged so the IP timestamp colum will be update. then when the other user tried to save the IP address status a conflict will happen since the IP address timestamp was chnaged so a cOptimisticConcurrencyException will be raised

Comment: What you have the unique key is already optimistic concurrency, the only additional info you get from timestamp is to let the user know when the locking occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case, it can be assumed as the right thing to do. It's easy to implement and maintain. You just have to document this (on paper and code).

The timestamp can be used as a concurrent check, but in your case, adding the constraint to the database is more than sufficient since nobody will insert duplicated records and who else tries will receive a message telling why. (Considering you will treat the specific exception and show the according message)

Answer (score 2):

Any column that's supposed to contain unique values should be declared unique. The constraints `primary key` and `not null unique` are behaviorally identical. (Not counting the side effects of implicit clustered indexes, for example.)

For example, [a table of states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6380089/562459) for the USA might be created like this.

```
CREATE TABLE states (
  state varchar(15) primary key,
  abbr varchar(10) not null unique,
  postal_code char(2) not null unique
);
```